# Can probabilities be defined on $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: probability, number-theory

Given positive integers $\mathbb{N}$ (excluding zero), can a probability be defined on this space? I believe yes, for example, whether a number is odd has probability 1/2.

Can a probability be defined on this space in such a way that any two numbers are equally likely to occur? This I am not sure about.

Comment: I can't say for certain one way or the other. What I do know is that is far more common (and acceptable) to define a density on the naturals rather than a probability: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density

Comment: While probabilities (more formally, probability distributions) can be defined on the natural numbers (or on the integers), one cannot define these so that "any two numbers are equally likely to occur".  It is possible to work around this impossibility in certain ways to give meaning to "a number is odd has probability 1/2".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, we assume that probabilities are countably additive. If you assume that the probability of each number is the same, then it is impossible for it to add up to one --- either you choose all of them to have zero probability --- and then, by countable additivity, the probability of choosing any number at all would be zero, which wouldn't make sense --- or you choose all of them to have the same nonzero probability $\varepsilon>0$, which unfortunately wouldn't make much sense, either, not even for finitely additive probabilities: as soon as you take $\lceil \varepsilon^{-1}\rceil+1$ numbers, you would end up with a set of numbers which has probability more than $1$!

If you drop countable additivity, however, then there are ways of doing that. Perhaps the simplest probability measure is the density measure, given by $d(A)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\# A\cap [0,n-1]}{n}$. It has the property you asked for: all natural numbers have the same probability (namely, $0$), the set of even numbers has measure $1/2$, and others you would naturally expect to be true. A downside is, it does not actually measure all sets of natural numbers.

You can make it measure all subsets by choosing a limit in the case where the above sequence does not converge (by means of an ultrafilter). This way, you can obtain an additive measure on the power set of natural numbers which is invariant under translation. This is called a Banach mean (this is related to the concept of an amenable group, namely that the group of integers is amenable).

Comment: Thanks! Assuming countable additivity and ignoring the part about all probabilities being equally likely, does it violate probability axioms to say P(1) = 1 and P(any number except 1) = 0? Does this define a valid probability on the natural numbers?

Comment: @phi: It does. Not a particularly interesting one, but it does. A more useful, countably additive probability measure is given by the exponential/Poisson distribution.

Answer (score 1):

No to your second question.  Since probabilities of elements have to total to 1, if they are all equal, then $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} P(n) \in \{0, \infty\} \not\ni 1.$$

Comment: The sum could be $\infty$ or $0$. But the conclusion is the same.

Comment: @phi Maybe that's not the question you intended..but if $P(a)=P(b)$ for any two $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$, then they are all equal.  Were you asking something else?

Comment: All of this assumes no nonstandard quantities. If you allow for infinitesimals, you could (relatively) easily define the probability of each natural as the infinitesimal equal to $1/H$ for some infinite hyperinteger $H$, then $1=\sum_{i=1}^H \frac{1}{H}$

Comment: @R.Burton: Should you allow that, you would end up with $\sum_{n\in {\mathbf N}} P(n)<1$. If the sum would actually converge, then maybe you could work around it with the correct scaling, but I'm not sure whether that would even make sense right now.